# How can I create a base from this Swift class so that it can be inherited?

Tags: ios, swift

I have a class named `UserManager`.

```
public class UserManager{
    static let sharedInstance = UserManager()
    let center = NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter()
    let queue = NSOperationQueue.mainQueue()

    var resources = Dictionary<Int, User>()
    var clients = Dictionary<Int, Set<String>>()

    private init(){

    }

    private func addToClientMap(id: Int, clientName: String){
        if clients[id] == nil {
            clients[id] = Set<String>()
            clients[id]!.insert(clientName)
        }else{
            clients[id]!.insert(clientName)
        }
    }

    func getResource(id: Int, clientName: String) -> User?{
        if let resource = resources[id] {
            addToClientMap(id, clientName: clientName)
            return resource
        }else{
            return nil
        }
    }

    func createResource(data:JSON, clientName: String) -> User? {
        if let id = data["id"].int {
            if let resource = resources[id] { 
                addToClientMap(id, clientName: clientName)
                return resource
            }else{ 
                resources[id] = mapJSONToUser(data) //need to make generic
                addToClientMap(id, clientName: clientName)
                return resources[id]
            }
        }
        return nil
    }

    func releaseResource(id: Int, clientName: String){
        if clients[id] != nil {
            clients[id]!.remove(clientName)
            if clients[id]!.count == 0 { 
                resources.removeValueForKey(id)
                clients.removeValueForKey(id)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Notice that I have an object called `User`, and it's used everywhere in this class.

I'd like to have classes called `PostManager` and `AdminManager`, which uses the same logic as the class above.

I could simply copy and paste the code above and **replace** the object `User` with `Post` and `Admin`.  But...obviously this is bad practice.

What can I do to this class so that it accepts **any** resource? Not just `User`

Comment: @matt my current class accepts ```User``` as the object. I want to make that arbitrary so that I can use any object. Right now, it's hard coded to return ```User``` in many of the methods.

Comment: How do I "derive from a common superclass"? This is where I need help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most obvious way to do something like this is to embed all of the generic functionality in a generic class, then inherit your UserManager from that:

```
protocol Managable {
    init(json:JSON)
}

public class Manager<T:Manageable> {
    let center = NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter()
    let queue = NSOperationQueue.mainQueue()

    var resources = Dictionary<Int, T>()
    var clients = Dictionary<Int, Set<String>>()

    private init(){

    }

    private func addToClientMap(id: Int, clientName: String){
        if clients[id] == nil {
            clients[id] = Set<String>()
            clients[id]!.insert(clientName)
        }else{
            clients[id]!.insert(clientName)
        }
    }

    func getResource(id: Int, clientName: String) -> T?{
        if let resource = resources[id] {
            addToClientMap(id, clientName: clientName)
            return resource
        }else{
            return nil
        }
    }

    func createResource(data:JSON, clientName: String) -> T? {
        if let id = data["id"].int {
            if let resource = resources[id] {
                addToClientMap(id, clientName: clientName)
                return resource
            }else{
                resources[id] = T(json:data) //need to make generic
                addToClientMap(id, clientName: clientName)
                return resources[id]
            }
        }
        return nil
    }

    func releaseResource(id: Int, clientName: String){
        if clients[id] != nil {
            clients[id]!.remove(clientName)
            if clients[id]!.count == 0 {
                resources.removeValueForKey(id)
                clients.removeValueForKey(id)
            }
        }
    }
}

class User : Managable {
    required init(json:JSON) {

    }
}

class UserManager : Manager<User> {
    static var instance = UserManager()
}
```

Now then, any class that implements the `Manageable` protocol (ie., it has an `init(json:JSON)` method can have a Manager class variant.  Note that since a generic class can't have a static property, that's been moved into the subclass.

Comment: The syntax `class Manager<T>` make Manager a "generic" class, you should be able to find that in your reference material (including the swift book from Apple.  `class Manager<T:Manageable>` says that T has to implement Manageable.

Answer (score 0):

Given that inheritance can hide implementation details, if reference semantics are not needed then a protocol + associated type (generics) implementation using structs might be safer and arguably more "Swifty".

Define your protocol with an **associated type (Swift 2.2)** or type alias (Swift 2.1):

```
protocol Manager {
    associatedtype MyManagedObject   // use typealias instead for Swift 2.1

    func getResource(id: Int, clientName: String) -> MyManagedObject?
    func createResource(data: JSON, clientName: String) -> MyManagedObject?
    func releaseResource(id: Int, clientName: String)
}
```

And then your implementation becomes:

```
public struct UserManager: Manager {
    typealias MyManagedObject = User

    func getResource(id: Int, clientName: String) -> User? { ... }
    func createResource(data: JSON, clientName: String) -> User? { ... }
    func releaseResource(id: Int, clientName: String) { ... }
}
```

And you can further add objects using the same protocol easily, specifying what 'MyManagedObject' should be:

```
public struct PostManager: Manager {
    typealias MyManagedObject = Post

    func getResource(id: Int, clientName: String) -> Post? { ... }
    func createResource(data: JSON, clientName: String) -> Post? { ... }
    func releaseResource(id: Int, clientName: String) { ... }
}
```

I would recommend reading up more on protocols and generics in detail (there are many examples online, [Apple's documentation is a good place to start](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Generics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH26-XID_234)).

Comment: In Swift 2.2, `typealias` in protocols is replaced with `associatedtype`.